# openpyxl, copying and pasting data to different positions in a different worksheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to copy cells D8:G41 from 'Sheet1' 'Parent Participation by Class 2017-2018.xlsx' and then *write* into B7:G40 of 'Per Class Report' 'AF17 Participation Report 2017-6-14'

Here is my code, with all loose ends:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


wb_raw_data = load_workbook(filename = 'Parent Participation by Class 2017-2018.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb_raw_data.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

wb_to_change_data = load_workbook(filename = 'AF17 Participation Report 2017-6-14.xlsx')

sheet2 = wb_to_change_data.get_sheet_by_name('Per Class Report')


for row_num_copy in range(8,41):    #iterate through the rows
    for col_num_copy in range(4,6): #iterate through col_num


# need to be pasted to 'AF17 Participation Report 2017-6-14.xlsx'
#                                               for row_num_paste in range(2,4):
#                                                   for col_num_past in range(7,40):



wb_to_change_data.save('AF17 Participation Report 2017-6-14.xlsx')
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What in the openpyxl  library will allow me after selecting an array of cells to copy them into another worksheet in another workbook, at a particular cell-location?

(I am trying to achieve pushing new data through documents without opening anything, except running the .py program.)

Comment: It's not possible Your Range(D8:G41)=136 Cells does not match Range(B7:G40)=204 Cells. If you could align the Number Cells it can be done.